# How to Minimize Query

Tags: query

current query-

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext param1) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator(
        'SELECT Id, RelatedRecord.timezonesidKey, ResourceType FROM ServiceResource WHEERE ResourceType = \'T\' AND isActive = true AND RelatedRecord.isActive = true AND Id NOT IN (SELECT ResourceId FROM ResourceAbsence WHERE End > :dateEffect )'
    );
```

I am tring to change with below but not working

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext param1) {
    Set<Id> resourceIdSet = new Set<Id>();
    for( ResourceAbsence rAb: [SELECT ResourceId FROM ResourceAbsence WHERE End > :dateEffect]){
        resourceIdSet.add(rAb.ResourceId);
    }

    return Database.getQueryLocator(
        'SELECT Id, RelatedRecord.timezonesidKey, ResourceType FROM ServiceResource WHERE ResourceType  = \'T\' AND isActive = true AND RelatedRecord.isActive = true AND Id NOT IN :RAbsence'
    );
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. What do you mean by "minimize query"?  Please [edit] your post to  clarify what you are trying to do and include more detail about the specific problem.

Comment: What's the issue with the first attempt? It looks to me like that's the one you ought to be using here (generally speaking, the fewer queries you have, the better). In this particular situation, keeping it as a single query probably avoids issues with the query row limit (which your second attempt may run into).

Comment: Also, if you're getting an error message, _you need to include it, verbatim_. Like I've told you before, we can't read your mind or see your screen. You _need_ to include details if you have any hope of getting an accurate answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the provided snippet there is no reason for a dynamic query, so a static one would be a wiser choise: if you misspell a variable or a field or something else, you'll get an error while trying to deploy/save the class, while with a dynamic query you'll get the error at runtime. Always prefer getting an error at compile time over one at runtime.
Moreover with a static query Salesforce is able to know that there is a dependency between the class and some metadata (object, fields, etc...).

Finally the name of your Set is `resourceIdSet`, while in the query string you used `RAbsence`, which is never defined. If it's been static query, you wouldn't been able to save the class.
Try changing it to:

```java
Set<Id> resourceIdSet = new Set<Id>();
for( ResourceAbsence rAb: [SELECT ResourceId FROM ResourceAbsence WHERE End > :dateEffect]){
    resourceIdSet.add(rAb.ResourceId);
}

return Database.getQueryLocator(
    [SELECT RelatedRecord.timezonesidKey, ResourceType
     FROM ServiceResource
     WHERE ResourceType = 'T' AND isActive = true AND RelatedRecord.isActive = true AND Id NOT IN :resourceIdSet]
);
```